# Subclass of NSViewController: use of 'self' in delegating initializer before self.init is called Error

Tags: swift, initialization

I'm trying to subclass an NSViewController but it doesn't compile.
I get an "use of 'self' in delegating initializer before self.init is called" error in the convenient init().

How can I get ride of it?

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

class HxLabelsViewController : NSViewController{

let LABEL_VIEW_NIB_NAME = "LabelsView"

convenience init() {
    self.init( nibName: LABEL_VIEW_NIB_NAME, bundle: nil)
}

override init!(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init( nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the constant out of the class, like this:

```
let LABEL_VIEW_NIB_NAME = "LabelsView"

class HxLabelsViewController : NSViewController {
    convenience init() {
        self.init( nibName: LABEL_VIEW_NIB_NAME, bundle: nil)
    }
    // ...
}
```